# Excel VBA speed up code to hide rows/delete color

Tags: excel, rows

I am using following code to delete color and hide rows that include several criteria before exporting sheets to pdf's. Is there any way to speed up this process as it is taking quite a lot of time to process. Especially in situations when I have several sheets in one workbook and to apply this on each sheet = "printed page".

```
Sub Color()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").Range("Print_Area")
        For Each cell In myRange
        myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        If cell.HasFormula = True And cell.Value = "" And cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps better on the Code review Stack.

Comment: What is the size of `Range("Print_Area")`? Also, you are checking every single cell in the range, even when you have already hidden the row. Another option would be trying to duplicate that sheet, and then select at once all those blank cells and delete them, and then delete the duplicate sheet (so your original data won't be affected). Check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would simply add a helper column right next to print area and just loop through those cells to hide/unhide rows , e.g. if you print area is A1:J1000 rather then looping 10000 cells you'll just be looping through 1000 cells.